Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain in React Native
I have a problem running a react native project, i'm using yarn but the error is also shown with npm:
$ yarn android

yarn run v1.22.22
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1990 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

    at makeError (/Users/.../app/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/.../app/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/.../app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/.../app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I'm using:

Node: v18.20.3
Yarn: 1.22.22
Java: java version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16 LTS
react-native: 0.69.4
react: 18.0.0
android 13 (emulator)
OS: MacOS Sonoma 14.4 (M1)

The project is running for the first time and has the following versions in the package.json file:
{
  "private": true,
 ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^8.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.8.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.35.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1289.0",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "6",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^10.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-get-location": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.1.4",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-rename": "^3.2.12",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-simple-encryption": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-switch-selector": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.14.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

And this is the content of the gradle-wrapper.properties file
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

and this is the content of the android/build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.10"

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.1") // I made the verion changes here between 7.6 and 7.6.1
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}


try downloading and adding the file gradle-wrapper-7.6.jar in the path: android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper-7.6.jar, but the result is the same.

I also tried to rebuild the gradle with command ./gradlew wrapper and it returns this error


./gradlew wrapper
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

I tried to change the gradlew version in gradle-wrapper.properties and android/build.gradle files and add the gradle.wrapper in version 7.6.1 but the error persists.

When I faced this issue (today) I resolved this by fixing my .gitignore. The expo build uses git commit, and my issue was that my .gitignore in my mono-repo contained a line to exclude all .jar files. So I had to explicitly allow the gradle-wrapper.jar to be included..
The !.. line in the file below is explicitly allowing it.
.gitignore:
# Package files
*.jar
!**/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

Also refer to the much older discussions here for other solutions, if your gitignore wasn't the issue:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
How to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain error?

